# User: arn:aws:sts::****:assumed-role/aws-lambda-execute/**** is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth on resource: arn:aws:cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, vercel, identity-management

Thanks in advace for the help!

I am encountering an error when deploying my frontend nextjs code on vercel, whereas the same code is working correctly on my local machine.

I am using aws lambda and cognito service. lambda already deployed but and its work fine with nextjs local application but when i deploy nextjs app then its gives me the permission issue at the time of login.

> AccessDeniedException: User:
> arn:aws:sts::672624023363:assumed-role/aws-lambda-execute/80a5c4b676c2fd90d3fee4d9b88ff4d1e8f99360429f3df3aa079adeffdecdf0
> is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth on
> resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:6726240

[image]

Comment: "deploying my code on Versal", what is Versal? what is type of your application? which AWS service you are using? What task you are performing when you get this error. Please update your question with all this info.

Comment: Hi @AnkushJain, thanks for your replay and sorry for the typo :). I have updated my question. Its nextjs application. Its working on on my local system but when i deploy it, it showing the the permission issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this issue on **Vercel**, and not on local is because  AWS credentials seems to be missing on Vercel server.

On local machine, you might be having the aws credential profile configured and that profile might be having sufficient permissions to assume the required role.

### Solution

1. Create an IAM user with sufficient permissions, and generate security credentials.
2. Add following [AWS environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) on your Vercel server where your application is running.

   ```
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your access key id>
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your access secret key>
   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<aws region>
   ```

   See [Vercel docs here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) learn how to do this.

I also found another blog post explaining the same thing. You may read this as well - [How can I use AWS SDK Environment Variables on Vercel?](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-aws-sdk-environment-variables-on-vercel)